# python unicode replace backslash u with an empty string

Tags: python

I'm sanitizing a pandas dataframe and encounters unicode string that has a `u` inside it with a backslash than I need to replace e.g.

```
u'\u2014'.replace('\u','')
Result: u'\u2014'
```

I've tried encoding it as `utf-8` then decoding it but that didn't work and I feel there must be an easier way around this.

## pandas code

```
merged['Rank World Bank'] = merged['Rank World Bank'].astype(str)
```

Error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2014' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: This is not sanitizing, this is insanitizing. You would be corrupting data that way.

Comment: `'\u2014'` is an em dash. Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: to turn the column into a str

Comment: updating question

Comment: where? @InAFlash

Comment: I still don't understand why you want plain strings and not Unicode strings. What will you do with data that uses other non-ASCII Unicode characters?

Comment: BTW, Unicode handling is a lot nicer in Python 3. In the mean time, you may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Also see the official Python [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) and [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) by SO co-founder Joel Spolsky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`u'\u2014'` is actually `-`. It's not a number. It's a `utf-8` character. Try using print keyword to print it . You will know

This is the output in ipython:

```
In [4]: print("val = ", u'\u2014')
val =  —
```

Based on your comment, here is what you are doing wrong
"-" is not same as "EM Dash" Unicode character(u'\u2014')

So, you should do the following

```
print(u'\u2014'.replace("\u2014",""))
```

and that will work

EDIT:
since you are using python 2.x, you have to encode it with utf-8 as follows

```
u'\u2014'.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8').replace("-","")
```

Comment: this is just as bad since it looks like it's almost impossible to remove the trailing characters. This `u'\u2014'.replace('—','')` throws an error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: You should note that "-" is not equal to u'\u2014'

Comment: you should do the following u'\u2014'.replace("\u2014","")

Comment: Are you using python 2.x?

Comment: @SamuelM. Try this, which works in both Python 2 & 3: `s = u'em\u2014dash'; print(s); s=s.replace(u'—', ''); print(s)`

Comment: u'\u2014'.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8').replace("-","")

Comment: Why on earth are you doing `.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')`? That takes a Unicode string, encodes it to UTF-8 bytes and then decodes those bytes back to the original Unicode.

Comment: @PM2Ring just trying some suggestion

Comment: "`u'\u2014'` is [...] a utf-8 character". No its not. It's a string containing a Unicode character. UTF-8 is an encoding of Unicode. The UTF-8 encoding of `u'\u2014'` is this 3 byte sequence: `'\xe2\x80\x94'`, which in Python 3 would be written as `b'\xe2\x80\x94'`. (You can also use that notation in Python 2).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, Because it is taking '2014' followed by '\u' as a unicode string and not a string literal.

Things that can help:

- Converting to ascii using .encode('ascii', 'ignore')
- As you are using pandas, you can use 'encoding' parameter and pass 'ascii' there.
- Do this instead : u'\u2014'.replace(u'\u2014', u'2014').encode('ascii', 'ignore')

Hope this helps.